# maxchunks in ledmac and ledpar

Tags: ledmac

What is the idea behind the command `\maxchunks` in the ledmac/ledpar-package?

Of course, I understand that I get an error when I have used, say, 15 times `\pstart ... \pend` while `\maxchunks` is set to `{10}`. But then I just increase the value of `\maxchunks` to `{15}` or `{20}` or even `{100}`.

So, why not using `\maxchunks{1000000}`? Is there any reason or recommendation for not using a value that high?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\maxchunks` internally allocates box registers and the problem is that there's only a limited number of those registers (256). You can set `\maxchunks` up to 56 without problems, but using

```
\maxchunks{57}
```

will trigger the

```
! No room for a new \count .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi
```

error. Loading the [etex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etex) package, you have now 32768 available box registers; you can increase the `\maxchunks` value up to 16346:

```
\usepackage{etex}
\maxchunks{16346}
```

but `\maxchunks{16347}` will trigger the error once again.

Comment: wow, Thank you. Additional Questions: (1) Do I have to load `etex` when I use Lualatex? I tried `\maxchunks{57}` but no error occured. (2) So there is absolutely no harm in using a lot of `\pstart ... \pend` and in increasing `maxchunks`?

Comment: @ClintEastwood: You're welcome! Regarding your additional questions: (1) no idea about LuaLaTeX, sorry. (2) Well, it depends; some packages can allocate boxes, and maybe you yourself also allocate some boxes other than those created bt \pstart, as long as the total number of allocated boxed doesn't exceed the maximum allowed, there's no risk (and using `etex` (at least with LaTeX) there's plenty of boxes available).

Comment: @ClintEastwood (continued). If, for some reason, you get out of boxes, ledpar recomendation is to either increase `\maxchunks` or use the parallel printing commands
(`\Columns` or `\Pages`) more frequently.

Comment: Well, in my case, when I have used too many chunks they start loosing syncronization. Therefore using \Pages as often as possible does'nt seem to me a bad idea. It also gives me the chance of adjusting \goalfraction manualy (if I find it convenient) for each set of chunks.